# New alias not available after ;

Tags: shell, alias

Up to now I thought that a semicolon in the shell has (somehow) the same meaning as a line break. So I was surprised that for

```
alias <name>=<replacement text>; <name>
```

`<name>` is unknown while it is known in the next line. `csh`, `tcsh`, `sh`, `ksh` and `bash` behave the same. At least for `csh` it does not matter if alias is used directly or if a script is sourced before the semccolon--the aliases are not known after `;` but the are known in the next command line. Is this a bug or is this behavior intended?

Comment: _"I thought that a semicolon in the shell has (somehow) the same meaning as a line break"_ Nearly. Not quite!

Comment: The interpretation of  semicolon and newline depends on how the parser is called. For the "dot" command, the Bourne Shell calls the parser with the "NLFLG" that tells it to treat  newline and semicolon equal in some situations, but this is not the case elsewhere. In general, semicolon and linebreak are not equivalent as you can have a linebreak, where a semicolon would cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alias syntax you are using is inappropriate for a POSIX shell, for a POSIX shell, you need to use:

```
alias name='replacement'
```

But for all shells, this cannot work as the alias replacement is done early in the parser.

Before your alias setup is executed, the whole line was read by the parser and for this reason, your command line wil not work.

If the alias appears on the next command line, it will work.

Comment: In addition, some shells like `yash` or `zsh` would not expand the alias in `shell -c 'alias name=replacement<newline>replacement'`. For AT&T `ksh`, you'd have the problem with _sourced_ scripts.

Comment: I need to use the csh in this case--there no `=` is used in the `alias` syntax.

Comment: @user3224237 - this has nothing to do with the `=`.  it is because the alias expansion happens when the shell first sees the line, which is **before** you define the alias.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas The behavior with "sourced" scripts is caused by the fact that the Bourne shell completely parses such files before they are execured. Ksh is based on the Bourne Shell source and everything that was not changed behaves the same.

Comment: @schily, yes, it's the same reason for `zsh/yash -c 'code'` where `code` is parsed as a whole. It doesn't seem to be the case for the Bourne shell.  So I suppose the Bourne shell parses that `code` there one line at a time.

Comment: See my other comment...on the question

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is intended and specified by POSIX under [Alias Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01).

An alias was substituted right after the shell perform [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) and before any [Grammar Rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) applied. At the time you called the alias `<name>`, the command `alias` wasn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want **one-liner**, then you can **use function instead of alias**.

E.g. you  make `py3` alias, but it only works in second line:

```
$ alias py3=python3; py3 -c 'print("hello, world")'

Command 'py3' not found, did you mean:

  command 'py' from deb pythonpy
  command 'hy3' from deb python3-hy
  command 'pyp' from deb pyp

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

$ py3 -c 'print("hello, world")'
hello, world
```

You can define `py3` as `function` instead of `alias`:

```
$ function py3() { python3 "$@"; }; py3 -c 'print("hello, world")'
hello, world
```

Or `export -f` before used in child process later:

```
$ function py3() { python3 "$@"; }; export -f py3; bash -c "py3 -c 'print("'"hello, world"'")'"
hello, world
```

And if you be aware the difference of [variable vs alias/function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342735/bash-command-whats-the-difference-between-a-variable-and-an-alias), then you can use **variable** too:

```
$ py3='python3'; $py3 -c 'print("hello, world")'
hello, world
```

and no need `export -f`:

```
$ py3='python3'; bash -c "$py3 -c 'print("'"hello, world"'")'"
hello, world
```