# `env foo=bar echo $foo` prints nothing

Tags: environment-variables

I think I'm having a massive brainfart. I would expect

```
env foo=bar echo $foo
```

...to print `bar`, but I get an empty line instead. Wat.

The same happens if I use the bash syntax:

```
foo=bar echo $foo
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A similar question was answered [recently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240274/new-alias-not-available-after/240279#240279): the symbols are evaluated in the line before the symbol is defined in this line, making it necessary to split the definition and use of the symbols to separate lines.

Prompted by a comment, you could have done this:

```
foo=bar bash -c 'echo $foo'
```

which first assigns a value to `foo` and passes that into a new process as an environment variable where it can be printed.

You can read more about it in POSIX Shell Command Language [Token recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01#tag_18_03).

Following up from [@mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv) comment:

- POSIX is not explicit enough to give the whole answer.
- At the beginning of the cited section, it says

  > The shell shall read its input in terms of lines from a file, from a terminal in the case of an interactive shell, or from a string in the case of sh -c or system().
- at the end, it says

  > Once a token is delimited, it is categorized as required by the grammar in Shell Grammar.
- but POSIX does not say *explicitly* that the entire line is tokenized before working on the grammar.
- in that case, we rely on existing practice - the shell conforms because nothing contradicts the written standard, but the standard cannot be used to predict the behavior in all cases.
- the same comment applies, of course, to the behavior of aliases (which is why I referred to it as a *similar* question).

Comment: or if you are okay with quoting hell, `env foo=bar bash -c 'echo $foo'`

Comment: Actually, the alias question relies upon the token-recognition section's implication that tokens are all computed for a given line before moving on to the grammar.  But for both, the standard is not *explicit*, making you rely on existing practice.

Comment: @thomasdickey - yeah, that was my gist too. you know, when you're writing a comment if you do *`@username...comment`* the user you specify will get a little message letting them know you were talking to them. well, they will if its thread-relevant.

Comment: @mikeserv (like this).  hmm - I'll keep that in mind (though how it works with embedded blanks was not apparent).

Comment: like that. tangentially, i had a look at `luit.c` and i *think* i can just change `setup_io(){ ... ;fnctl(0, [GS]ETFL, 0);...}` to do `2` for the first argument. well, i guess the `copyTermios()` and `setRawTermios()` functions might need a little modification as well, but it should be simple, i think. the `rc = (return)` for every line seems strange - but i'm no C programmer either. is that your thing or was that inherited? and if your blanks comment is referring to `"${set_null_var:=new val and $(echo other stuff)}"` you're mostly safe w/ anything. some shells will do weird stuff with `}`.

Comment: The order is quite clearly specified [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) and [there](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01), assignments are only done after expansions in non-redir and non-assignment words have been done.

Comment: If it were *explicit*, the second link would mention that it is an invarying order of steps to be performed, rather than *implying* it as was done using the wording "general overview of operations".  I considered that in my comments earlier, and did not overlook it.