# How to execute alias right after sourcing it in a one liner?

Tags: alias

I'm trying to write a one liner that sources aliases, then calls one of those newly sourced aliases. My one liner is basically:

```
alias startEnv sourceAliasFile;runNewAlias
```

Since I'm using csh, I can't make a function. When I run this, my source executes but my new alias doesn't exist yet and does not execute. Why does this not work and is there a way to get around it?

Comment: I think this post answers the question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240274/new-alias-not-available-after?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the alias definition and use are all on one line.  You might work around this by writing the alias definition to a temporary file and sourcing that.  But aside from that — you need to have the statements on separate lines (semicolons don't count for the parser in this case).

Comment: It's an interesting one, because doing `alias foo ls; alias` shows that `foo` is aliased to `ls`, so CSH knows that the alias has occurred...(on FreeBSD 10.3)